# Unable to explode from PHP StdClass Object

Tags: php, explode

i am unable to explode an STDclass variable i have values in the object some what like mentioned below, but when i take the dump i get

I have  `stdClass Object ( [page_path] => 14-45-55 )`. When i try to explode this

```
$pages = $database->executeObjectList("SELECT page_path FROM tblwebpages WHERE page_id=" . $_GET['id']);
$explodedString = explode('-', $pages->page_path);
print_r($explodedString);  
exit;
```

on taking dump of ($explodedString) i get

```
Array ( [0] => )
```

can i know what am i doing wrong if?

Comment: What do you mean by "i am unable to explode"?  What does that mean?  What happens?  Do you see the wrong result?  An error?  Does your computer explode?  Something else?

Comment: well i guess, i didnt mentioned the dump in the end i repharsed the questioni guess u can get it now

Comment: What do you see if you do: `var_dump($pages, $pages->page_path)`?

Comment: You can't explode an object or array. This only applies to strings. You should check if `$pages->page_path` exists and if gives a value you can process.

Comment: @JamesPoulson He's not trying to explode the object, he's trying to explode the value of the `page_path` property of the object.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: i get this Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [page_path] => 14-45-55 ) )

Comment: `$explodedString = explode('-', $pages[0]->page_path);`

Comment: @RocketHazmat For that the OP should check the value (using a print_r ?) as suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `$pages`, according to your comment, is actually an array (containing an object).

You need to do this instead:

```
$explodedString = explode('-', $pages[0]->page_path);
```

Comment: @JamesPoulson: He showed his `var_dump` and it said "Array" ;-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19716632/unable-to-explode-from-php-stdclass-object/19716761#comment29291241_19716632

Comment: Very true, and i got the answer